# Devise uninitialize constant Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I realize this has been asked many times on here (I also read through the wiki). But I am still confused at how to properly keep my route names the same.

Currently my devise routes are below, using custom url's (for example `/user/signup`).

My model is called `User`

Routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, :path_names => {
    :sign_up => 'signup'
  }

  devise_for :users, :path => "user", :except => "create", :path_names => { 
    :sign_in  => 'login', 
    :sign_out => 'logout', 
    :password => 'forgot-password', 
    :confirmation => 'verification', 
    :unlock   => 'unblock', 
    :sign_up  => 'signup' 
  }
```

All I am trying to do is hook into the create action so I can check if a honeypot field I have created is filled out (to prevent spam). That's really all I want to do.

I want to keep my url the same though `/user/signup`. Is there an extra step I need to do?

This is what I have so far in...

**/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

end
```

I am getting `uninitialized constant Users`

Comment: possible duplicate of [devise overriding registrations controller - uninitialized constant Users::RegistrationsController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466822/devise-overriding-registrations-controller-uninitialized-constant-usersregis)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quite simply I needed to put the controller in a 'users' folder, and that fixed everything. (Also, the route controller needs to be `:registrations => "users/registrations"`

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Mine worked only when i used the singular noun, i.e.  
```devise_for :users, controllers: {
      :registration => "users/registrations"
  }```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same error. 
in my case it was in `routes.rb`

was: `devise_for :users,controllers: {sessions: "users/sessions"}`

result: `uninitialized constant Users`

I had no idea what's going on till `{sessions: "users/sessions"}`
in my case it should be `user/sessions` without "s"

Comment: its funny you have commented on a project that died 3 years ago

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to name the controller `Users::RegistrationsController`, just name it `RegistrationsController` keeping the inheritance from `Devise::RegistrationsController`.

I don't know the purpose of the first `devise_for` but you need to copy/move `:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }` to the second `devise_for`.

Answer (score 1):

On `devise (4.7.3)` and `rails (6.0.3.3)` the correct controller is `Session` not `Sessions`.

You need to add this in your `config/route.rb`

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { session: 'users/sessions' }
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed my problem!