# Routing Error - uninitialized constant Users::RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, uninitialized-constant

I have started on a web application for user registration etc. using devise gem. I am novice to Ruby/Rails env. So this is part of my training.

My question is very similar to an old posting @ [devise overriding registrations controller - uninitialized constant Users::RegistrationsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466822/devise-overriding-registrations-controller-uninitialized-constant-usersregis)

After the homepage displays, when I click on signup button, I get this error. I have done some research on this issue on the web to no avail.

In app/controllers/users/registrations_controllers.rb I have this code:

```
   class Users::RegistrationsController < Device::RegistrationsController

    def create
      super do |resource|
        if params[:plan]
           resource.plan_id = params[:plan]
           if resource.plan_id == 2
              resource.save_with_payment
           else
              resource.save
           end
         end
       end
     end  
    end
```

In Routes.rb I have this line of code:

```
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations =>         'users/registrations' }
```

Please let me know if you need any other information to help resolve this error.

Comment: Try `app/controllers/users/registrations.controllers.rb` it should be `registrations_controller.rb`. rename file name

Comment: Instead of using the shortcut notation `Users::RegistrationsController`, try wrapping it in a `Users` module: `module Users; class RegistrationsController`

Comment: @Sontya actually I have it as registrations_controller.rb and not as registrations.controller.rb and its still not working.

Comment: @janfoeh I am not sure how to do that, so if you could elaborate I would really appreciate it...this is my first app and still trying to understand all the crazy terminology!

Comment: There's also a typo in the first line: `Device::RegistrationsController
`

Comment: @joship https://gist.github.com/janfoeh/711a5043491e904a2305

Comment: @janfoeh - you also used `Device` in your code

Comment: @niiru Thanks for noticing another typo! but the error still exists after correcting it and restarting Webrick server.

Comment: @Sontya tried your way also, same error persists!

Comment: @janfoeh tried the module Users per your suggestion, restarted server, still no change!

Comment: where is `sign_up` button, where is that page is located, show the path. and your user model too

Comment: @Sontya  https://github.com/joshipv/saas_app  if you want to see the entire app so far..

Comment: Thanks everyone. So finally what worked was moving the registrations_controller out of app/controller/users folder back into app/controller itself. I am in disbelief as whatever I was taught is once again negated. This is the reality of software development business we have come to live with.

Comment: What branch? I don't see the controller anywhere.

Comment: hey this can be closed out now...I have found the solution myself which was moving the registrations_controller out of users folder and back into it. Strange but true. Its hard to understand the way rails works sometimes. I am ending this now. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In `routes.rb`, try:

```
devise_for :users,
  :skip => [:registrations, :sessions]

as user do
  # Registrations
  get   '/signup'   => 'users/registrations#new', as: :new_user_registration
  post  '/signup'   => 'users/registrations#create', as: :user_registration
```

It should work.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was looking for hours on how to stop Devise overriding controllers and didn't see this anywhere. This finally solved my problem.